# $scope does not update for ng-show correctly when value changes and force doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angularjs

Using ng-show it does not display my div whenever I changed the value in the controller.  I even tried forcing the $scope by using apply but it causes a continuous loop of refreshing the page since it hits the other conditional due to the first condition not displaying.

html:

```
<div class="halloweenMsg" ng-show="isHalloween">
  <div>Happy Halloween!</div>
</div>

<div class="thanksgivingMsg" ng-show="isThanksgiving">
  <div>Happy Thanksgiving!</div>
</div>

<div class="christmasMsg" ng-show="isChristmas">
  <div>Merry Christmas!</div>
</div>

<div class="newyearsMsg" ng-show="isNewYears">
  <div>Happy New Years!</div>
</div>
```

controller:

```
var holidays = {
    HALLOWEEN : 10,
    THANKSGIVING : 11,
    CHRISTMAS: 12,
        NEW_YEARS: 1,
        NONE: 99
}

$scope.isHalloween = false;
$scope.isThanksgiving = false;
$scope.isChristmas = false;
$scope.isNewYears = false;

$scope.displayHandler = {
   displayHoliday: function (holidayVal) {
        if(holidayVal=== holidays.HALLOWEEN) {
           $scope.isHalloween = true;
        } else if (holidayVal=== holidays.THANKSGIVING) {
           $scope.isThanksgiving = true;
        } else if (holidayVal=== holidays.CHRISTMAS) {
           $scope.isChristmas = true;
        } else if (holidayVal=== holidays.NEW_YEARS) {
            $scope.isNewYears = true;
     } else {
            // refresh page since nothing was correct
            $window.location.href = '/'
        }
   }
}

$http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: '/someUrl'
}).then(function (response) {
    if(response.data.holiday === 'Halloween Day') {
        $scope.displayHandler.displayHoliday(holidays.HALLOWEEN);
    } else if (response.data.holiday === 'Thanksgiving Day') {
    $scope.displayHandler.displayHoliday(holidays.THANKSGIVING);
    } else if (response.data.holiday === 'Christmas Day') {
    $scope.displayHandler.displayHoliday(holidays.CHRISTMAS);
    } else if (response.data.holiday === 'new Years Day') {
    $scope.displayHandler.displayHoliday(holidays.NEW_YEARS);
    } else {
         $scope.displayHandler.displayHoliday(holidays.NONE);
     }
}).catch(function (error) {
});
```

After looking around I tried these fixes but nothing works, it either does not display the correct div or displays the wrong div and then refreshes over and over.
First attempt to change I tried setting the ng-show to check the string true but it didn't change anything and the div did not show still:

```
<div class="halloweenMsg" ng-show="isHalloween === true;">
```

Second try was using the wrapping the $apply around each setting of the ng-show value, but then it does the continuous loop thinking the digest cycle was not done and kept going for some reason and hits the else statement and refreshes the page continuously:

```
$scope.$apply(function() {
 $scope.isHalloween = true;
});
```

Last was to either put a timeout or checking a $digest was already in progress and not kick off a new one.  This however then works only occasionally and not showing divs consistently.

```
if(!$scope.$$phase) {
   $scope.$apply(function() {
      $scope.isHalloween = true;
   });
}
```

Not sure what else to try and make sure things fire correctly when set since it seems the $scope at this point is not in sync when using the displayHandler in the http post response evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

Just a few simple errors to correct.

First, your `if/else` structure is not correct. All the `else` statements should be `else if` except the final one.

Next, change this: `$window/location.href = '/'`
to: `$window.location.href = '/'`

Here is a working solution:

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
var myApp = angular.module('spicyApp1', []);

myApp.controller('SpicyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
var holidays = {
    HALLOWEEN : 10,
    THANKSGIVING : 11,
    CHRISTMAS: 12,
    NEW_YEARS: 1
}

$scope.isHalloween = false;
$scope.isThanksgiving = false;
$scope.isChristmas = false;
$scope.isNewYears = false;

$scope.displayHandler = {
   displayHoliday: function (holidayVal) {
        if(holidayVal=== holidays.HALLOWEEN) {
           $scope.isHalloween = true;
        } else if(holidayVal=== holidays.THANKSGIVING) {
           $scope.isThanksgiving = true;
        } else if(holidayVal=== holidays.CHRISTMAS) {
           $scope.isChristmas = true;
        } else if(holidayVal=== holidays.NEW_YEARS) {
            $scope.isNewYears = true;
        } else {
            // refresh page since nothing was correct
            $window.location.href = '/'
        }
   }
}
$scope.displayHandler.displayHoliday(holidays.HALLOWEEN);

            
}]);
})(window.angular);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-controller-spicy-1-production</title>
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  

  
</head>
<body ng-app="spicyApp1">
  <div ng-controller="SpicyController">
<div class="halloweenMsg" ng-show="isHalloween">
  <div>Happy Halloween!</div>
</div>

<div class="thanksgivingMsg" ng-show="isThanksgiving">
  <div>Happy Thanksgiving!</div>
</div>

<div class="christmasMsg" ng-show="isChristmas">
  <div>Merry Christmas!</div>
</div>

<div class="newyearsMsg" ng-show="isNewYears">
  <div>Happy New Years!</div>
</div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Randy, sorry all the errors you pointed out were copy and paste or my bad mistyped mistakes.  I had it correct in my code but I checked and have it similar to what you have but it does not work still.   I will have to double check again but something is causing an error still.